# Can I cast a vote on my own popularity contest?

Tags: discussion

I've just posted a popularity-contest question, and I'm curious about the rules on myself casting a vote. Am I allowed/should I vote on my favourite answer, or should I leave it up to everyone else's votes?

Comment: Yes, you can vote on answers to your own questions, even for popcons. :-) IMHO. I mean, you can cast at most one vote per answer, and I can't imagine that being a tiebreaker.

Comment: I thought that said "even for popcorn" at first haha. Cool, thanks :)

Comment: Who would even know? Vote in any way you'd like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, by all means cast your vote(s), both up *and* down as you feel appropriate.